# Scraping dropdown menu values by Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, combobox, dropdown, screen-scraping

I check most of the posts, but didnt find a reply for my small quation.

### **This the dropdown which i want to *scrape*:**

```
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[138]" id="attribute138" class="required-entry super-attribute select form-control" onchange="notifyMe(this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);">
        <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
        <option value="17" price="0">M (in stock) </option>
        <option value="18" price="0">L (out of stock) </option>
        <option value="15" price="0">XL (in stock) </option>
        <option value="52" price="0">XXL (in stock) </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**My Python Code is:**

```
items = soup.select('option[value]')
values = [item.get('value') for item in items]
textvalues = [item.text for item in items]

print(textvalues)
```

**And Output is :**
['select', '(In-Stock)', '(Out-Stock)', '(In-Stock)', '(In-Stock)']

**My request is i also need the other values (SizeValue & SizeName):**
17 & M / 18 & L / 15 & XL / 52 & XXL

**If i removed the .text , i have this output:**

```
   <option value="">select</option>, <option value="200@#-(In-Stock)@#-https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html@#-">(In-Stock)</option>, <option value="201@#-(Out-Stock)@#-https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html@#-">(Out-Stock)</option>, <option value="202@#-(In-Stock)@#-https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html@#-">(In-Stock)</option>, <option value="203@#-(In-Stock)@#-https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html@#-">(In-Stock)</option>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, just add a `+` and also call `item.text` in your list-comprehension.

Instead of:

```
values = [item.get('value') for item in items]
```

use:

```
values = [item.get('value') + item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items[1:]]
print(values)
```

---

**EDIT**: The data is loaded dynamically so `requests` doesn't support it. But the data *is available* in JSON format on the website. You can extract it with a Regular Expression using the `re` module:

```
import json
import re
import requests


url = "https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html"
response = requests.get(url).content

regex_pattern = re.compile(r"Product\.Config\(({.*?})\);")
data = json.loads(regex_pattern.search(str(response)).group(1))

print(
    [
        product["id"] + product["label"]
        for product in data["attributes"]["138"]["options"]
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
['17M (in stock) ', '18L (out of stock) ', '15XL (in stock) ', '52XXL (in stock) ']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, i tried that, but the problem the output is diffrent as below:

Comment: @TalalIsmail What's the URL? also don't post such as an answer, instead, as a comment. (like you just did)

Comment: Ok Sorry, this is my first time to come to stack overflow.

Comment: https://store.alsabihmarine.com/index.php/diving-equipments/wetsuits/camouflage-hooded-suits-220.html

Comment: Thanks alot, i understood now it was dynamic value.
It is working great.